# Elasticsearch Date_Histogram does not cover entire filter

Tags: elasticsearch, date-histogram

I'm using ES [Date Histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) and a weird behavior started happening and I'm wondering why.

This is the request i'm sending to elasticsearch:

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "range": {
                              "publishTime": {
                                 "from": "2010-07-02T12:15:20.000Z",
                                 "to": "2015-07-08T12:43:59.000Z"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "agg|date_histogram|publishTime": {
         "date_histogram": {
            "field": "publishTime",
            "interval": "1d",
            "min_doc_count": 0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The result i'm getting are buckets, and the first bucket is:

```
{
   "key_as_string": "2010-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
   "key": 1282608000000,
   "doc_count": 1
}
```

So i'm filtering from 2010-07-02 and getting results only from 2010-08-24

This is just an example, I also saw this behavior with many more missing buckets (several months).

[edit]
this seems to correlate with the date of the first result, meaning that the first result in that time range is from 2010-08-24, but as I included `"min_doc_count": 0` I expect to get results from that entire range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`min_doc_count` is only sufficient for returning empty buckets between the first and last documents matched by your filter. If you want to get results for the entire range you need to use [`extended_bounds`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation-extended-bounds) as well:

```
  "aggs": {
      "agg|date_histogram|publishTime": {
         "date_histogram": {
            "field": "publishTime",
            "interval": "1d",
            "min_doc_count": 0
            "extended_bounds": {
                "min": 1278072920000, 
                "max": 1436359439000
            }
         }
      }
   }
```